# Cannot connect to my tcp tor hidden service in Python

Tags: python, tor, stem

I have a fully functional tor hidden service with his v3 url, created with stem and the controller class. The server is redirecting the traffic into a local tcp server running on port 5000 created with `socket`. But now I want to connect to this hidden service using python. So I tried `socks` with SOCKS5 proxies, no way of making it work. I also tried the `torpy` library with the example provided on the offical doc but, again, no way to make it works:

```
from torpy import TorClient

url = 'myv3torurl.onion'

tor = TorClient()
with tor.create_circuit() as circuit:
    print('circuit done')
    with circuit.create_stream(('http://' + url, 5000)) as client:
        print('sending')
        client.send(b'yeah yeah im there')
        print(client.recv(1024))
```

Also tried changing the url adding http:// or https://, or tried to change the port with 80, 9050 or 9051. The `torpy` logs are always the same and you can find them [here](https://pastebin.com/P8egAP1p).

At this point I do not really know what to try. I just want a tcp connection hosted by the onion website. And by the way, I'm sure it's not a problem of the server because if I try to copy and paste the url on the tor browser it is fully reachable. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Your error happens at the function [here](https://github.com/torpyorg/torpy/blob/c0b2b6dedf4d1456e373a2d0ed44cf4286391b9a/torpy/circuit.py#L633). If you can check the calls of that code then you can tell that it reaches line 668 without executing the main loop on line 651. I would also recommend asking the on `tor.stackExchange` if you can.

Comment: I asked that a month ago here and on stackExchange... received no asks... and i am still on this problem

Answer (score 4):

Noticed that torpy page says it is for v2 services and yours is v3.